# How to get another field value from model if I know first field value?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to learn django and faced problem accessing models.

I have model in `models.py` that look like this:

```
class Countries(models.Model):

    Country = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    PPP = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Country
```

Now in `views.py` I want to make some calculations based on user input. User will choose value from first field (`Country`) and I need to find second field value (`PPP`) based on that.

It means that I have data structured something like that:

```
Country   | PPP
----------------
Lithuania | 0.45
Germany   | 0.86
Estonia   | 0.55
Spain     | 0.77
```

So I will know country and I will need to access its PPP. How should I do it?

Because various solutions I tried gives me an error.

Lats solutions I tired:

```
pVal = str(form.cleaned_data['Country'])
country = Countries.objects.first()
pValKof = getattr(country, pVal)
```

Based on my research I feel I should be somewhere near the solution, but I just can't understand `getattr` completely. Or maybe there is some other way to achieve this?

EDIT: Here is relevant part of my `forms.py`

```
class PGPskaiciuokle(forms.Form):

    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Countries.objects.all(),
                                       label="Choose country")

    def clean_country(self):
        country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        return country
```

Comment: Please post your forms.py

Comment: Added relevant part, sorry I thought it was irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Changed my solution, because I missed the fact that the Form's field was a ModelChoiceField

Instead of:

```
pVal = str(form.cleaned_data['Country'])
country = Countries.objects.first()
pValKof = getattr(country, pVal)
```

Do this:

```
country = form.cleaned_data['Country']
ppp = country.PPP
```

Furthermore:

1. Properties in Python should start with a lowercase letter, classes with an uppercase letter, so instead of Country and PPP, use country and ppp (Not sure what ppp stands for, it wouldn't hurt to use a more descriptive name)
2. A model name should be singular. So instead of Countries, use Country
3. The property Country could be more descriptive. Try using name instead of country.
4. I would opt for a unique name for each country.

So to clean up your code a bit:

```
class Country(models.Model):

        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)

        ppp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

And

```
country = form.cleaned_data['country']
ppp = country.PPP
```

And the form file:

```
class PGPskaiciuokle(forms.Form):

    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(),
                                   label="Choose country")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
country = form.cleaned_data['Country']
ppp = country.PPP
```

This gets the `Countries` object from which you can easily get the `PPP`. You are able get the `Countires` object because you are using a `ModelChoiceField` in your form.

Some bonus tips:

- Name your models as a singular (eg: `Country` instead of `Countries`)
- Name you class variables as all lowercase
- You don't need the `def clean_country(self):` method in your form

Comment: Thank you for the tips, cleaned my code, it was more difficult to catch all the places where old names were used than I was expecting. In the future I better write it right on the first time.