# Iterating list and collecting corresponding field value from model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have model which consist of three fields and in the table should look something like this:

```
drg_code | drg_kof  |  drg_count
---------+----------+------------
A08A     | 0.45     |  215
A08B     | 0.75     |  656
B03A     | 0.33     |  541
B03C     | 0.22     |  125
```

Code for it models.py

```
class DrgCode(models.Model):

    drg_code = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    drg_kof = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)

    drg_count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.drg_code
```

I created form for user input which returns QuerySet of drg_code variables. It looks like this in in `print`: `<QuerySet [<DrgCode: A05Z>, <DrgCode: A06A>, <DrgCode: A06C>]>`. So I converted it into list.

Now I need to iterate through that list and using `drg_code` variables, find corresponding model fields values, and store them in separate lists so in the end I should end with 3 lists: one for `drg_code`, one for `drg_kof` and one for `drg_count` (these list will be needed for future calculations).

I tried using method from my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804017/how-to-get-another-field-value-from-model-if-i-know-first-field-value), but I keep getting error `AttributeError` saying `'str' object has no attribute 'objects'` or similar (depending on code variation I tried) on  `obj = DRGkodas.objects.first()` line.

My relevant view.py code:

```
from catalog.models import DrgCode
from catalog.forms import DrgCalculator

#up to this part everything works so I emit irrelevant code
chosen_drg = form.cleaned_data['drg_choose'] 

psrDRG_list = list([str(i) for i in chosen_drg]) #converting QuerySet into list (seems to work fine)

            psr_atv_sk = [] #list for drg_count variables
            psr_atv_kof = [] #list for drg_kof variables

            for item in psrDRG_list:
                drg_code = item
                obj = DrgCode.objects.first()
                atv_sk = getattr(obj, drg_code)
                psr_atv_sk.append(atv_sk)
                '''
                 in here I tried different approach of
                 getting corresponding field value, but do
                 not know if it works since code never
                 reached this part
                '''
                atv_kof = DrgCode.drg_kof
                psr_atv_kof.append(atv_kof)
```

Why I am getting `AttributeError` what I am doing wrong? And am I correctly trying to catch corresponding field values? Which method is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get)

```
DrgCode.objects.get(drg_code = item)
```

Also read about `first()`  [see](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Comment: Still getting AttributeError `'str' object has no attribute 'objects'` on `obj = DrgCode.objects.get(drg_code = item)` line. I do not understand why.

Comment: @Gexas I found this interesting answer on why you are getting AttributeError, Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926420/4984493

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid, since I wrote code in my native language (variable names in native) then I posted code here and translated it for easier reading I emitted original reason why I was getting and error - variable name in `models.py` and  `views.py` was the same so I was getting AttributeError because of that.

Other than that, Mahmoud Adel answer got me on the right track. Code for accessing another field value looks like this:

```
for item in psrDRG_list:
    obj = DrgCode.objects.get(drg_code = item)
    atv_sk = obj.drg_count
```